# AngularJS: The "best" way to bind a Factory variable to a $scope or a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a new AngularJS project, and encountered a problem that annoys me more than it actually should...

I have an Angular Service containing data I need to access from multiple views and controllers, and updated by another Service which is receiving continuous data from a server, via SocketIO.

Something like :

```
angular.module('Foo', [])

.factory('DataContainer', function(){  
    var data = [];
    var o = {};
    o.all = function() {
        return data;
    };
    o.add = function(item){
        data.push(item);
    };
    return o; 
})

.factory('DataReceiver', function(DataContainer){
    var o = {}
    o.init = function(){
         socket = io.connect()
         .on('data', function(item){
              DataContainer.add(item);
         };
    };
   return o;
})

.directive('dataList', function(DataContainer) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</li></ul>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.data = DataContainer.all();
        }
    };
});
```

Problem is that "dataList" does update when DataContainer.add() is call from the parent's controller, but does not when DataContainer.data is updated by the DataReceiver service (as the $scope itself does not update).

I tried many things, including things like :

```
$scope.data = DataContainer;
.....
ng-repeat="item in data.all() track by $index"
```

thinking it could solve my problem. But it didn't.

I'm now considering using **$rootScope**, or **$watch** combined with a **$scope.apply()** to pass and update my data, but it sounds pretty heavy, and I'm not sure it's the proper way to go...

What am I doing wrong ? Any proper way to bind a Service variable to a controller $scope or a directive ? 
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.factory('DataReceiver', function(DataContainer, $rootScope){
    var o = {}
    o.init = function(){
         socket = io.connect()
         .on('data', function(item){
              DataContainer.add(item);
              $rootScope.$apply()
         };
    };
   return o;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't have `push` function in `DataContainer` yet you are trying to call here

```
.factory('DataReceiver', function(DataContainer){
    var o = {}
    o.init = function(){
         socket = io.connect()
         .on('data', function(item){
              DataContainer.push(item);
         };
    };
   return o;
})
```

you should either call `DataContainer.data.push(item)` or create a function `push` in `Datacontainer` service or you should call `Datacontainer.add(item)`

Comment: just call `Datacontainer.add(item)`

Comment: Woops, just a mistake from copying my code. That's actually my point : I'm calling DataContainer.add() (or any other method that push, splice, my data array) from DataReceiver, but it only updates my directive / controller $scope if I call this method from the directive or controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$rootScope.$broadcast()` method in `Datacontainer.add()`. for Example,`$rootScope.$broadcast("datarecived");` in `Datacontainer.add()` and in directive.inject $rootScope and add:

```
$rootScope.$on("datarecived",function(e,obj)
{
   scope.data = DataContainer.all();
})
```